# Can I run two external monitors on a 2012 MacBook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt-display, dual-screen

computer: MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) - 1TB SSD - Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB - 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 - 2.9 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i7

Currently, have one monitor setup using a thunderbolt to HDMI adapter all good there, but how can I add another external monitor? The second monitor has a VGA, DisplayPort, HDMI, and USB 2 port. Both monitors are HP.

What's the cheapest way to run two external monitors in this situation? I would prefer an HDMI cable method since I already have two of these. I will not have my MacBook open when using two monitors. Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: Mactracker says it will support 2 thunderbolt displays.

Comment: What's the resolution on the displays? Specs says max resolution is 2560x1600, but I'm doubtful it will support 2 of those, given later models don't.

Comment: yeah but i already have two monitors and i asked for the cheapest way to connect these two so im not looking to buy two expensive thunderbolt displays

- 1920 x 1080